# Jmeter Distributed testing results 403/Forbidden

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

Run jmeter distributed testing,all machines are gcp instances.Able to trigger tests from master to  slaves.Problem is test results getting 100% Error rate  403/Forbidden. This happens on all the vms.I'm running a sample script with no external data files e.g csv,so it should be all pass. **On running the tests on my local they pass just fine**.
Master & slaves using same version of jmeter,java and plugins

> server.log of one of the vms

```
    2022-09-02 07:12:13,318 INFO o.a.j.e.RemoteJMeterEngineImpl: Running test
2022-09-02 07:12:13,330 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test!
2022-09-02 07:12:13,330 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2022-09-02 07:12:13,356 INFO o.a.j.e.u.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must contain the string: '.functions.'
2022-09-02 07:12:13,356 INFO o.a.j.e.u.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must not contain the string: '.gui.'
2022-09-02 07:12:13,822 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Users
2022-09-02 07:12:13,822 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 10 threads for group Users.
2022-09-02 07:12:13,822 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error
2022-09-02 07:12:13,823 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group... number=1 threads=10 ramp-up=10 delayedStart=false
2022-09-02 07:12:13,851 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: Note: Sample TimeStamps are START times
2022-09-02 07:12:13,851 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.default.encoding is set to ISO-8859-1
2022-09-02 07:12:13,851 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.useNanoTime=true
2022-09-02 07:12:13,851 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.nanoThreadSleep=5000
2022-09-02 07:12:13,854 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: 10.10.52.197-Users 1-1
2022-09-02 07:12:13,912 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPHCAbstractImpl: Local host = jmeter-worker-prf-002
2022-09-02 07:12:13,913 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1
2022-09-02 07:12:13,913 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started
2022-09-02 07:12:13,928 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPHC4Impl: HTTP request retry count = 0
2022-09-02 07:12:14,024 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.h.LazyLayeredConnectionSocketFactory: Setting up HTTPS TrustAll Socket Factory
2022-09-02 07:12:14,029 INFO o.a.j.u.JsseSSLManager: Using default SSL protocol: TLS
2022-09-02 07:12:14,029 INFO o.a.j.u.JsseSSLManager: SSL session context: per-thread
2022-09-02 07:12:14,034 INFO o.a.j.u.SSLManager: JmeterKeyStore Location:  type JKS
2022-09-02 07:12:14,035 INFO o.a.j.u.SSLManager: KeyStore created OK
2022-09-02 07:12:14,035 WARN o.a.j.u.SSLManager: Keystore file not found, loading empty keystore
2022-09-02 07:12:14,504 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.10.52.197-Users 1-1
2022-09-02 07:12:14,504 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.10.52.197-Users 1-1
2022-09-02 07:12:14,852 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: 10.10.52.197-Users 1-2
2022-09-02 07:12:15,094 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.10.52.197-Users 1-2
2022-09-02 07:12:15,094 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.10.52.197-Users 1-2
2022-09-02 07:12:15,847 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: 10.10.52.197-Users 1-3
2022-09-02 07:12:16,076 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.10.52.197-Users 1-3
2022-09-02 07:12:16,076 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.10.52.197-Users 1-3
2022-09-02 07:12:16,840 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: 10.10.52.197-Users 1-4
2022-09-02 07:12:17,059 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.10.52.197-Users 1-4
2022-09-02 07:12:17,059 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.10.52.197-Users 1-4
2022-09-02 07:12:17,840 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: 10.10.52.197-Users 1-5
2022-09-02 07:12:18,063 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.10.52.197-Users 1-5
2022-09-02 07:12:18,063 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.10.52.197-Users 1-5
2022-09-02 07:12:18,831 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: 10.10.52.197-Users 1-6
2022-09-02 07:12:19,052 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.10.52.197-Users 1-6
2022-09-02 07:12:19,052 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.10.52.197-Users 1-6
2022-09-02 07:12:19,843 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: 10.10.52.197-Users 1-7
2022-09-02 07:12:20,076 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.10.52.197-Users 1-7
2022-09-02 07:12:20,076 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.10.52.197-Users 1-7
2022-09-02 07:12:20,829 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: 10.10.52.197-Users 1-8
2022-09-02 07:12:21,148 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.10.52.197-Users 1-8
2022-09-02 07:12:21,148 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.10.52.197-Users 1-8
2022-09-02 07:12:21,845 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: 10.10.52.197-Users 1-9
2022-09-02 07:12:22,052 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.10.52.197-Users 1-9
2022-09-02 07:12:22,052 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.10.52.197-Users 1-9
2022-09-02 07:12:22,841 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: 10.10.52.197-Users 1-10
2022-09-02 07:12:23,092 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 10.10.52.197-Users 1-10
2022-09-02 07:12:23,092 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 10.10.52.197-Users 1-10
```

the only error i see is

> 2022-09-02 07:12:14,035 WARN o.a.j.u.SSLManager: Keystore file not
> found, loading empty keystore

could that be the issue?though i didnt load any keystore on local

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) file doesn't tell the full story (at least until you [enable debug logging](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging))

First of all try temporarily enabling saving of request and response details for local and remote runs and compare resulting [.jtl files](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles). By default JMeter stores metrics in CSV format so you either need to amend [Results File Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config) or add a Listener like [Simple Data Writer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer) and configure what and where to store

[image]

if the requests are the same enable debug logging and compare jmeter.log files. If there are no suspicious entries there try running your test from a machine on GCP in [command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) (not-distributed test run) as it might be the case your application doesn't allow incoming traffic from there

Comment: Tried every step,,ran with one vm non -distributed and still got the 403,turns out you were right application doesn't allow incoming traffic from the vms ,informed devops resource and this is fixed now,,,thanx again